# Restricted Cauchy identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, young-tableaux, schur-functions

Is there some reference for sums like:
$$\sum_{\nu \subset \mathrm{[1,n] x[1, m]}}s_{\nu}(x)s_{\nu}(y)t^{|\nu|}$$
$$\sum_{\nu \subset \mathrm{[1,n] x[1, m]}}s_{\nu}(x)s_{\nu}(y)\cdot|\nu|$$
(summation over diagrams lying inside the box of length $m$ and width $n$) or specializations with all $x_i = y_j = 1$ ? Any of these will be sufficient for me.

edit: $s_{\nu}(x)$ depends on $x_1, ..., x_n$, while $s_{\nu}(y)$ on any number of variables.

Comment: what are the cardinalities of the alphabets? n and m, or something else?

Comment: @user61318 cardinalities are: $n$ for $x$'s and any for $y$'s. Sorry for not specifying it.

Comment: The Cauchy-identities goes hand in hand with RSK, https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/schur.htm#schurCauchyFormula 
and https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/rsk.htm#rsk
See the references given there for proofs.
The second identity should follow from the first by taking derivative, and setting t=1..

Comment: The first one should be a sum over integer matrices, such that the corresponding biwords (see RSK) has some restriction on longest increasing subsequence, and |t| is simply sum of entries in the matrix...